# Webpack 3: Use sass-loader and ExtractTextPlugin doesn't work

Tags: webpack, sass, sass-loader, extract-text-plugin

I've been trying to use the sass-loader in webpack and I follow this instructions -> https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin#extracting-sass-or-less but this not working.

**Can anybody help me?**

**Repository**

https://github.com/gpincheiraa/boolean-html-js-exercises/tree/dev

**Error**

```
ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module build failed: Error: "extract-text-webpack-plugin" loader is used without the corresponding plugin, refer to https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin for the usage example

  - Error: "extract-text-webpack-plugin" loader is used without the corresponding plugin, refer to https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin for the usage example
```

**Dependencies**

```
node v6.11.1
npm 5.3.0

├── babel-cli@6.26.0
├── babel-loader@7.1.2
├── babel-plugin-transform-class-properties@6.24.1
├── babel-polyfill@6.26.0
├── babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1
├── babel-preset-stage-3@6.24.1
├── css-loader@0.28.7
├── extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.0
├── html-loader@0.5.1
├── html-webpack-plugin@2.30.1
├── markdown-loader@2.0.1
├── node-sass@4.5.3
├── sass-loader@6.0.6
├── style-loader@0.18.2
├── webpack@3.5.6
└── webpack-dev-server@2.7.1
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
      "./index.js"
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "index.bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" },
            { test: /\.md$/, loaders: [ "html-loader", "markdown-loader" ] },
            { test: /\.scss$/,
              use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                  fallback: 'style-loader',
                  use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
              })
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css'),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: 'index.html',
          inject: 'body'
        })
    ],
    devtool: "eval-source-map",
    devServer: {
        filename: "index.bundle.js",
        contentBase: "./",
        port: 3000,
        publicPath: "/",
        stats: {
            colors: true
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue comes from the [commented style code in your `index.html`](https://github.com/gpincheiraa/boolean-html-js-exercises/blob/5e5f5a7/index.html#L9-L20). The `index.html` is processed by the `html-webpack-plugin` and for some reason it still tries to process the require calls ([line 9](https://github.com/gpincheiraa/boolean-html-js-exercises/blob/5e5f5a7a49dc1db953ddf426499e9188f4051321/index.html#L9) and [line 11](https://github.com/gpincheiraa/boolean-html-js-exercises/blob/5e5f5a7a49dc1db953ddf426499e9188f4051321/index.html#L11)). The reason could be the custom EJS loader of `html-webpack-plugin`.

The easiest solution is to fully remove the commented code from `index.html`.

By importing a `.scss` file, the rule you configured gets applied to it. But it seems that the actual `extract-text-webpack-plugin` instance isn't available during that process. You are using an inline loader in these require calls, but your configured rules will still be applied to that. To prevent other loaders from being applied, you can prefix the import with a `!`.

From the [webpack documentation - `Rule.enforce`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-enforce):

> All normal loaders can be omitted (overridden) by prefixing `!` in the request.
>
> All normal and pre loaders can be omitted (overridden) by prefixing `-!` in the request.
>
> All normal, post and pre loaders can be omitted (overridden) by prefixing `!!` in the request.

To be able to use the CSS correctly in your HTML you'll also need to use `css-loader` after the `sass-loader`, because EJS expects JavaScript at this place, not bare CSS. The require would become:

```
<%= require("!css-loader!sass-loader!\./sass/index.scss") %>
```

It would also be better to import `index.scss` in your actual application instead of the template that is used by `html-webpack-plugin`.

Comment: you saved my life.  Was a conceptual error from me. I've reading this docs: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md and finally I understand for completly. 
Thank you for you awesome response!

Comment: The change: https://github.com/gpincheiraa/boolean-html-js-exercises/commit/2290ff64079d9e6ced40d2cf1f82d2f612ca8745

Answer (score 0):

I came here because my configuration with Webpack 3 + Sass + React wasn't working either.

However, in my case the problem was very stupid. I must say I created the project with `create-react-app` tool and it sets a `webpack.config.dev.js` file with a quiet complex/complete configuration.

The problem was that I was adding the `sass` rule **AFTER** the `exclude` one and it clearly says in the comments (hah) that every loader after that one will not work.

So it looks now like this and it works:

```
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [require.resolve('css-loader'), require.resolve('sass-loader')],
        })
      },
      {
        exclude: [/\.js$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
        loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
        options: {
          name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
        },
      },
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.